# Regex to check if String is numeric or the word "all"

Tags: java, regex

I know how to check if a String is a positive double but how can I incorporate the function to check if the word is sell also?

This is what I use to check for positive double

```
sell2.matches("[+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+"))
```

EDIT: Answer in comment

Comment: Use: `"[+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+|all"`

Answer (score -1):

```
private static final Pattern VALIDATOR = Pattern.compile("\\+?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?|all");
...
VALIDATOR.matcher(sell2).matches()
```

This is the regex you describe. Best have it compiled statically like this, otherwise calling `sell2.matches(...)` compiles it every time, and that's a performance hit.